# How to convert a collection to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a javascript collection (i.e. something returned from getElementsByTagName/etc) to a normal array so I can perform array functions on the data.

I'm looking for a solution **without** using any libraries and haven't been able to find any sort of elegant solutions anywhere online. Has anyone written a good util function for this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( coll, 0 );
```

---

**EDIT:** As [@Chris Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110164/chris-nielsen) noted, this fails in IE pre-9. Best would be to do some feature testing, and create a function that can handle either, or just do a loop as in [the (second) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158338/how-to-convert-a-collection-to-an-array-in-javascript/5158429#5158429) from [@brilliand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638544/brilliand).

Comment: Or save some typing: `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('div'), 0);`

Comment: @lwburk: True, but I personally wouldn't construct a new Array just to get at its `.slice()`, especially if I'm going to use this more than once. Though I'd consider your shorter version as a way to create a reusable reference. `var slice = [].slice; /*...*/ slice.call( coll, 0 );`

Comment: This fails in IE6, IE7, and IE8. Works in IE9.

Answer (score 33):

This has become a lot simpler in modern browsers. I'll outline two approaches, both supported by all major browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari, Firefox, Opera) since 2016.

### Spread operator

"Spread syntax allows an iterable (...) to be expanded"

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
const myArray = [...divs]; // [div, div, ...]
```

### Array.from

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) "*creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object*"

**Example: Convert an HTML collection to array**

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
const myArray = Array.from(divs); // [div, div, ...]
```

Answer (score 8):

Copy it to a regular array?

```
var coll = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var arr = [];
for(var i in coll) arr[i] = coll[i];
```

Been a while since I used JavaScript... you may need this instead:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) arr.push(coll[i]);
```

Comment: +1 for handling IE properly. The second solution is better for javascript.

Answer (score 8):

You can use spread operator:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var arr = [...coll];
```

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: This answer is underrated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.from as it creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an iterable. So An HTMLCollection is a collection of document elements.

So we can use Array.from to convert to an array them using for each to iterate over its elements of the array.

```
let  coll = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
let  ary= Array.from(col1);
Array.from(col1).forEach((elm=>elm.innextText='Example'));
```